# Echartjs disable datazoom slider on y-axis (gantt)

Tags: echarts

is there a way to disable the data zoom option on the axis (y-axis) in my case. As you can see from the screenshot there is the motion which I would like to disable. The scrollbar on the y-axis should just execute the scrolling and not th zooming:

[Gantt Chart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhSXb.jpg)

This is the json declaration for the datazoom option:

```js
type: 'slider', // horizontal scrollbar
    xAxisIndex: 0,
    filterMode: 'weakFilter',
    height: 17,
    bottom: 0,
    start: 0,
    //end: 26,
    end: 100,
    handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
    handleSize: '80%',
    showDetail: true,
    backgroundColor: sliderBgColor,
    fillerColor: sliderColor,
    handleStyle: {
        color: sliderHandleColor
    }
}, {
    type: 'inside', // horizontal mouse gestures
    id: 'insideX',
    xAxisIndex: 0,
    filterMode: 'weakFilter',
    start: 0,
    end: 26,
    zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
    moveOnMouseMove: true,
    moveOnMouseWheel: false
}, {
    type: 'slider', // vertical scrollbar  
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    zoomLock: true,
    width: 20,
    right: 0,
    top: 30,
    bottom: 20,
    show: _rawData.ganttRows.data.length > noOfRows,
    start: 0, // this defines the height of each line indirectly
    end: Math.min(100, noOfRows * 100 / _rawData.ganttRows.data.length),
    showDetail: false,
    backgroundColor: sliderBgColor,
    fillerColor: sliderColor,
    zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
    moveOnMouseMove: true,
    moveOnMouseWheel: true,
}, {
    type: 'inside', // vertical mouse gestures
    id: 'insideY',
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    start: 95,
    end: 100,
    zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
    moveOnMouseMove: true,
    moveOnMouseWheel: true // move up and down with mouse wheel
}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the option brushSelect in your slider:

```
type: 'slider',
    ...
    brushSelect: false,
```